# Shopify Script tag api return 400 HTTP error

Tags: php, api, curl, shopify

Shopify return HTTP 400 error when I made a request to script tag for creating script.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2016 22:16:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 400 Bad Request
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-ShopId: 11511010
X-ShardId: 2
X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit: 1/40
HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT: 1/40
X-Stats-UserId: 0
X-Stats-ApiClientId: 1253884
X-Stats-ApiPermissionId: 17250892
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=/xss-report/30fa40b7-e2b9-44a1-b6ef-a3b43b8b95e3?source%5Baction%5D=create&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fscript_tags&source%5Bsection%5D=admin
X-Request-Id: 30fa40b7-e2b9-44a1-b6ef-a3b43b8b95e3
X-Dc: chi2,ash

{"errors":{"script_tag":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}
```

Here is my code format:

```
$request_headers[] = "X-Shopify-Access-Token:".$token_id;
$request_headers[] = "Content-Type : application/json";

$ch = curl_init('https://revestore.myshopify.com/admin/script_tags.json');
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args); 
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);            
print_r($response);
```

If anyone know relative solution please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think it's a php problem, try your query using the curl command line, and when it works there it'll be easy to adopt it to php

Comment: This error would be caused by `$args` either missing a `script_tag` field or containing one that's not valid. As such, you've basically given us everything *except* the important bit - the value of `$args`.

Comment: here is my $args value,,  $args = array(
                                  "script_tag" =>array(
                                  "event" => "onload",
                                  "id" => "42343243",                                  
      "created_at" => "2015-08-24T14:01:47-04:00",
      "updated_at" => "2015-08-24T14:01:47-04:00",
                                  "src"=> "http://alliedshades.com/my_custom.js"));  

               $args = json_encode($args);

Comment: If you are want to create a new ScriptTag resource, the only params/$args you need are `event` and `src`. Setting the `id` is what I imagine is causing the problem (Also, lose the `created_at` and `updated_at`, it's supposed to be created by Shopify).

Answer (score 1):

If you are want to create a new ScriptTag resource, the only params/$args you need are `event` and `src`.

Setting the `id` is what I imagine is causing the problem

(Also, lose the `created_at` and `updated_at`, it's supposed to be created by Shopify when you create / modify the resource respectively)

Documentation on creating a ScriptTag resource:
https://docs.shopify.com/api/uiintegrations/scripttag#create

Comment: Yes I also tried only using src and event. But not working.  here is my JSON   :   $args = '{"script_tag": {
                                          "event": "onload",
                         "src": "http://alliedshades.com/my_custom.js"
                                          }
      
   }';

Answer (score 0):

Solve my issue. Here everything is okay. Just need http_build_query($query_string);  to process JSON string.